# Clases y funciones en PHP

Tags: php

estoy teniendo unos problemas con unas clases en php, para ser más exacto, unas dudas, no sé como funcionan las clases y funciones. 
Por ejemplo, si quisiera crear un objeto llamado imágen, que tenga 2 funciones como Subir y Borrar.

```
$imagen = new imagen("nombre", "formato");
$imagen->upload;
$imagen->delete;
```

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir el código de la clase Imagen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer del modo siguiente

```
<?php

class Imagen
{
    private $nombre;
    private $formato;

    public function __construct($nombre, $formato){
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->formato = $formato;
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        //código de alta
        $this->nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
        $nombrer = strtolower($this->nombre);
        $cd=$_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
        $ruta = "img/" . $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
        $destino = "img/".$nombrer;
        $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"], $ruta);
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        //código de eliminación
    }
}

$nuevaImagen = new Imagen("./sol.jpg", ".jpg");
$nuevaImagen->upload();
$nuevaImagen->delete();
```

> Del anterior código de entiende lo siguiente, la clase por dentro
>   recibe un constructor que recojerá dos propiedades; tanto nombre como
>   formato
>
> Los 2 métodos posteriores se encargarán de procesar alguna de las 2
>   acciones

Comment: Creo que no es buena práctica usar `@move_uploaded_file(/*...*/)`, y de usarlo, al menos explicar que hace, y el motivo de usarlo. Si tienes experiencia y conoces tu código, perfecto. Pero si no, puede ser una pesadilla encontrar errores. Ahí tienes mi +1.

Comment: No era necesario lo del script para subir archivos realmente, pero tu aporte está groso, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ser algo como:

```
class imagen {
    public function upload() {
      ejecuta función y retorna;
    }
    public function upload() {
      ejecuta función y retorna;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esa respuesta no me quita ninguna duda, pero por el esfuerzo te lo marco como útil, recuerda que responder por puntaje no sirve para nada ni nadie.